# Tooltip shows up underneath the element

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I've added a customized tooltip to my project. The tooltip is showing under the element when I hover over it. I'm not sure what's going on. It's only for some elements too. I've tried changing the tooltip position but it breaks the whole design. My desired need is that to display the tootip fully without hiding underneath parent element.

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 4px;
}

/* Tooltip styling */
[data-tooltip]:before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/* Dynamic horizontal centering */
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* Dynamic vertical centering */
[data-tooltip-position="right"]:before,
[data-tooltip-position="left"]:before {
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="right"]:before {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:before {
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="left"]:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

/* Tooltip arrow styling/placement */
[data-tooltip]:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}

/* Dynamic horizontal centering for the tooltip */
[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

/* Dynamic vertical centering for the tooltip */
[data-tooltip-position="right"]:after,
[data-tooltip-position="left"]:after {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

[data-tooltip-position="top"]:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0;
  border-top-color: #000;
}

[data-tooltip-position="right"]:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-width: 6px 6px 6px 0;
  border-right-color: #000;
}

[data-tooltip-position="bottom"]:after {
  top: 100%;
  border-width: 0 6px 6px;
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}

[data-tooltip-position="left"]:after {
  right: 100%;
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-left-color: #000;
}

/* Show the tooltip when hovering */
[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  display: block;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k2p51ac/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CSS issue, about overflow hidden.

Solution:
Just remove from this css rules:

1. .each_member_in_list .each_inlist {
2. .each_member_in_list {

This items:
overflow: hidden !important;
overflow: hidden;

Comment: thanks for the help i didn't checkd that previously. Now its working fine.